# Change the audio balance (L+R)

Tags: audio, windows-8.1

My pair of (expensive) earphones somehow broke yesterday; the sound coming out of the left earbud is tinny!
A few issues mainly involving the fact that the offices of the manufacturer are located on the other side of the world means that it's going to be trouble filing a warranty claim and get them sent off for a replacement.

I attempted to solve the problem by adjusting the [audio balance as seen here (works with Windows 8.1 also)](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-adjust-audio-balance-in-windows-7/), however I need to increase the volume of the left channel by around 25% to get a level sound, and this consequently means that 25% is always added onto the volume.
This basically means that I can't put the volume up that much when applying this 'fix'.

I've tried searching for other ways to achieve increasing the volume of the left channel whilst maintaining the audio volume of all channels in total, however I've been lead back to the same 'solution' that doesn't work.

I'd like to shift the actual balance of the volume in the left channel whilst not affecting the actual volume of Windows.
Is this possible, if so, how?